# checking whether a string is null using isEmpty()

Tags: java

Actually I tried to change null check of particular string,  previously

```
    {if (empName.equals("") || (empName.equals(null)))
//Do something 
}
```

which was not a proper way to check a string is null, as

```
    While ( empName == null) 
     {if (empName.equals("") || (empName.trim().IsEmpty()==true))
//Do something 
}
```

But it didn't work.can anyone suggest What's wrong with this?

Comment: if(empName ==null || empName.isEmpty()){ ... do stuff } should work

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response.. But will this check for  whitespace also @Angel koh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to change null check of particular string, previously
>
> ```
> if (empName.equals("") || (empName.equals(null)))
> ```

Two things are wrong with the above piece of code:

- if `empName` is `null`, you get an exception
- The call `empName.equals(null)` is required to return `false`, so it has no effect

A proper way of checking a string for being `null` or whitespace is as follows:

```
if (empName==null || empName.trim().isEmpty())
```

You do not need the `== true` part, because `isEmpty()` returns a `boolean`.

Comment: Thank you so much @dasblinkenlight it worked. But what was wrong with my work

Comment: @ani The call `empName.equals("")` throws an exception when `empName` is null.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of basic ideas that would be handy to have in mind here.  These are:

- Pointer Dereferencing
- Short Circuit Evaluation

**Pointer Dereferencing.**
In Java, types that are not primitive are called *reference types.*  The variables for these types do not contain the value for the type, instead they contain a pointer to memory.  For example:

```
String str;
```

String is a reference type.  Once initialized, the variable `str` will hold a reference or pointer to the memory location of the assigned String instance.  Until initialized, variables for reference types have the value `null`.

Before any member of a class instance (eg. methods or fields) can be accessed and used, the pointer for a reference type must be accessed to get the location of the member in memory.  This is called *dereferencing*. If a reference type variable contains the `null` value, then it is not possible to access any members.  This is why an expression like this one is perilous:

```
`if (myString.equals("")) ...`
```

If the variable `myString` contains `null` or is not initialized, it cannot be dereferenced to a heap location. In this case an exception is raised and your program fails.

If you cannot guarantee that a `String` variable won't contain `null` then you should not use statements like the one above because it may raise a `NullPointerException` in your code.

**Short Circuit Evaluation.**
Short circuit evaluation is where the evaluation of a multi-part expression is terminated before all of the parts have been evaluated -because- finishing the complete evaluation would not change the value of the expression.  This most commonly applies to boolean expressions.

Consider an expression like this:

```
if (myString.trim().isEmpty()) { ... }
```

As discussed above, this expression leaves the program vulnerable to `NullPointerExpressions` whenever myString contains `null` and cannot be dereferenced.  However this expression is safe:

```
if (myString == null || myString.trim().isEmpty) { ... }
```

In the above case, a `NullPointerException` can never be thrown by this expression, even if myString contains `null`.  If myString is equal to `null`, the first part of the expression is `true`.  In a boolean OR expression, `true OR xx`, the result of the expression is always true no matter what `xx` is.  The Java environment therefore only executes the 1st part and not the second part.  This is a good thing, because a NullPointerException would result if it had been.

Short circuit evaluation is commonly used in Java `if-then` expressions to test for null conditions that would raise exceptions in subsequent parts of a logical expression.

Comment: Thanks @scottb you made my java learning perfect . Will be needing your guidance throughout my java journey